# Architecture requirements to scale SQL Azure Tables/Schemas

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scalability, azure-sql-database, horizontal-scaling

I am setting up a schema/some tables in SQL Azure and wanted to know if there were any things i need to do architecturally in order to promote scalability, especially horizontal scalability. Should IDs be of a certain type? Primary keys be of a certain type?

I am looking to avoid risk/issues down the road... let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to please read the article [Scale Out with SQL Database (en-US)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1010.scale-out-with-sql-database-en-us.aspx) which explains ins details about what is needed for Horizontal Partitioning of your SQL Database.

Now you can also use SQL Federation with SQL Database so another article on [Scaling Out with SQL Azure Federation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh848258.aspx) will help you to decide the best architecture which can scale out when in need.