# How do Azure SQL scaling features change schema design?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

In other words, **how should schema design in Azure SQL differ from schema design for SQL on VM or hardware?** What additional factors should the DBA consider when designing schemas for Azure SQL databases and managed instances?

In order to narrow the question scope, you can limit your answer to **OLTP primary and cluster key selection and design.**

For some context for my admittedly broad question, I am not finding a definitive resource for guidance on schema design in the context of Azure SQL PaaS scaling features. When designing a database schema with Azure SQL in mind, what design choices will maximize the utility and ease the future implementation of scaling features, including **Sharding**, **SQL Data Sync**, **Read Scale-Out** and **Hyperscale**?

It is very likely that *'it depends'* is the correct answer (no green checkmark though.)

Even so, I think it an important question and want to start the conversation here in SO and get the most useful answers in one place.

The most correct answers will be **practical on a small scale** and will also be compatible with Azure SQL scaling features **without major refactoring**.

Other similar questions have outdated answers and were posted before many of these features were introduced:

[Architecture requirements to scale SQL Azure Tables/Schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165897/architecture-requirements-to-scale-sql-azure-tables-schemas)

[Primary key in an Azure SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172891/primary-key-in-an-azure-sql-database#21176702)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is a preference for database-per-tenant for multi-tenant solutions, as large numbers of databases spread across multiple Elastic Pools or Managed Instances is a lot simpler than on VMs or On-Prem.

Also the HA/DR solutions for Azure SQL Database impose limits on the log rate, so you will use Columnstore and Bulk Loading for large tables in OLAP and mixed workloads.